# Insert 2 date values into columns in sqlite db using python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

New to using sqlite with python. I am trying to insert two date values into two date columns in sqlite db via Python.

```
import sqlite3

def create_connection(db_file):
    # Create a database connection to a SQLite database
    # Param: db_file as str. Return: connection objects or None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        return conn, cur
    except Error as e:
        print (e)
        return None

my_conn, my_cur = create_connection(dpd_sqlite_db_dir)

def create_sqlite_table_if_nonexist(conn, table_name):
    sql = 'create table if not exists '+table_name+' (data_download_date datetime, script_executed_date datetime)'
    conn.execute(sql)

create_sqlite_table_if_nonexist(my_conn, 'df_timestamp_en')

def insert_timestamp(conn, timestamp):
    # execute insert into db
    sql = ''' INSERT INTO df_timestamp_en (data_download_date, script_executed_date) VALUES(?,?) '''
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql, timestamp)
    return cur

timestamp_info = ('2018-10-30', '2018-11-30')
insert_timestamp(my_conn, timestamp_info)
```

It runs and created the table with two date columns, but it doesn't insert the `timestamp_info`'s values.

Comment: you need to commmit with `conn.commit()`.

Comment: That's it. Thanks.